# Optimal packaging of Android image app

Tags: android, optimization, packaging, aapt

I'm working on an app which displays various images. I want to optimize this for the various screen resolutions. The MultiResolution (1) tutorial uses many resource qualifiers in the res folder to display the appropriate images for the various device resolutions, but how do you package this? I don't want to ship the images for all devices (or do I?). I want to keep the download size as small as possible, so I only want to package the ones for that particular screen resolution. Or, should I forget packaging images and put the images on-line somewhere?

Any opinions on this subject would be appreciated

(1) http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/MultiResolution/index....

Answer (score 0):

You will want to provide the resources for every screen size you want to support so that android does not use CPU and battery life scaling images.  Generally I use a drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-hdpi to cover the majority of devices.

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for your answer. My question however is, will your create a single app-package containing all the images, so it can be installed on all the devices? Or will you create a separate package for each device type (3 in your case), so that it only includes the images in the res-folder suitable for that particular device? That's the question. And if you split up the package, is there a nifty way to do that with aapt, or with the ADT-plugin tools?

Comment: Google requires one APK per application, not per device.  Hope that helps.